# showing the distance function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with $x_0 \in X$, with $f(x) = d(x,x_0)$. I am trying to prove that $f$ is continuous on $X$ so I have to show that

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $|x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

I start with $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |d(x,x_0)-d(x_0,x_0)| = |d(x,x_0)| = d(x,x_0)$ but I don't know how to use this to choose $\delta$

Comment: That statement is "$f$ is continuous at $x_0$" but not that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Use the triangle inequality to show that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$. Then given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon$. Finish the argument.

Comment: but is $d(x,y) = |x-y|$? I mean, I have $|x-y| < \delta$ is my definition of continuous wrong

Comment: No, not necessarily. To show that $f$ is continuous on $X$, you need to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $c\in X$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, $d(x,c) < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(c)| < \delta$.

Comment: I can't show the triangle inequality still, I have that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq d(x,x_0) + d(y,x_0)$ but we have that $d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_0) + d(x_0,y)$ how can I put these together

Comment: Since $f(x) = d(x,x_0) \le d(x,y) + d(y,y_0) \le d(x,y)  + f(y)$, we have $f(x) - f(y) \le d(x,y)$. Interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$, we get $f(y) - f(x) \le d(y,x) = d(x,y)$. Thus $|f(x) - f(y)| \le d(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The function $f$ was defined using $x_0$. If you want to prove that $f$ is continuous on $X$, prove that it is continuous in $a$, for all $a \in X$. Using only $x$, which is a variable, and $x_0$, which is fixed, with no regard for the point that you're analyzing continuity on, you won't get anywhere. Prove that $$|d(x,x_0)-d(x_0,a)| \leq d(x,a)$$and choose $\delta = \epsilon$.